# How to know which DNS served a request?

Tags: c, dns

My environment uses 3 DNS servers. 
With res_init (from resolv.h) I can retrieve the DNS server list of my Linux system.

With getnameinfo() I can resolve an IP address to a name.
But, how can I know what is the DNS server that has served the request or even if it is the local hosts file that was used ?

Any idea ?

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Comment: That information is not part of getnameinfo() API.

Comment: I agree. So, is there any other way to get such information ?

Comment: Depends on what context you need it. If you need your own program to figure out that, then probably not. If it's a debugging approach, you can run your program under the `strace` tool, and inspect what it's doing (you should be able to see if it creates a socket and sends UDP packets to a server on port 53 (DNS), etc.)